# Image not found or type unknown barryvdh\dompdf laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, dompdf

Hello for those who are using barryvdh\dompdf laravel. I have a problem with the image of the PDF that I am sending in email. My issue is that the image background would not show and it would say that `Image not found or type unknown.` It just occurs this week as in the past it is working fine. I test in my local and the image background is showing while in the server it is not showing.

epermit.blade.php

```
<img class="mx-auto" src="{{ asset('/images/permit.jpg') }}">
```

In my controller

```
$pdf = PDF::setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true])
               ->loadView('epermitpdf', compact('permit', 'student'));
        Storage::put('public/pdf/epermit.pdf', $pdf->output());
```

in mailable laravel

```
return $this->markdown('permit-markdown')->attach(Storage::disk('public')->path('pdf/epermit.pdf'));
```

I try exchanging another pathname in src such as `<img class="mx-auto" src="www.domain.com\permit">` as I try to put in a server to have easy access. It works for a while but after it would say again `Image not found or type unknown`.

Comment: you are saying on local it works but not on server, does both are using the same environment, I read from answer below you are using Win on local but are you using Win on server as well

Comment: Yes exactly sir. I used windows server and xampp as the server same with local

Comment: I have found one possible error, you have not mentioned disk when you insert using put, `Storage::disk('local')->put('public/pdf/epermit.pdf', $pdf->output());`

Comment: you can change local to public as well

Comment: okay sir i'll try that one. I hope it will be okay

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

`Storage::put('public/pdf/epermit.pdf', $pdf->output());`

to this

`Storage::put(public_path('pdf/epermit.pdf'), $pdf->output());`

then check if the file exists using your browser at

`www.your-website.com/pdf/epermit.pdf`

Comment: ```Impossible to create the root directory```

Comment: You need to double check the permissions on your public/pdf/ folder. You can try this, go to the main laravel folder via command line and type this (chown -R www-data:root .) or (chown -R www-data:www-data .)

Comment: chown would not work. I'm using windows and xampp

Comment: Ok on windows you should not need it. Can you paste in here the full path to your public/pdf folder including c:\full-path\

Comment: create a folder here - c:\xampp\htdocs\proj-name\public\pdf and try run the script again

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with this as well , tried SetOptions etc. And that's what solved the issue for me:

In the controller:

```
return PDF::loadView('your.view')->stream();
```

In the view:

```
<img src="{{public_path().'/storage/images/pdf/your_image.jpeg'}}">
```